# What is the different between who and whom

Tags: british-english

When I have been learning english I can not understand different between who and whom?

Comment: Yep, Mari-Lou's link answer this question comprehensively. For similar questions, you might be interested in our sister site, [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Note that we speak of **the** diferen**ce** between two or more things.

Answer (score -1):

*Who* is the subject of a sentence:

```
Who shot the sheriff?
The person who shot the sheriff must be arrested!
Who are you?
```

*Whom* is an object in a sentence:

```
To whom should I address this letter?
With whom should I attend the ball?
To whom does this belong?
```

More on this here: http://web.ku.edu/~edit/whom.html

Colloquially, *who* is often used instead of *whom*. Although this is generally accepted as incorrect, many say it anyway. It's not uncommon to hear these among native English speakers:

```
To who does this belong?
With who are you going to the ball?
```

In both instances *whom* would have been the right choice.